# Does Javascript have deferred collection APIs like .NET LINQ?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, collections, deferred-execution

I know Javascript Array has `map`, `filter` and the like, and `reduce` can be used as a way merge them (though I really dislike the syntax, it does work). However, a simple example below can prove that it is **not** deferred (i.e. it is executed right away at the function call).

In C# however, LINQ functions like `Where` and `Select` do not actually execute the expression until it is needed and (to my knowledge) only a final collection is ever allocated:

```cs
var a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var b = a.Where(q => q < 2).Select(q => q + 1); // This code is not actually executed here yet
var c = b.ToArray(); // Here an array is actually allocated

// c should be [ 2 ]
```

In the below Javascript, I believe two arrays are actually allocated and the expression is called right away:

```js
const a = [1,2,3];

const b = a.filter(q => { 
  console.log("filter executed");
  return q < 2;
});
console.log(b.constructor.name);

const c = b.map(q => {
  console.log("map executed")
  return q + 1;
});
console.log(c.constructor.name);
// c should be [ 2 ]
```

The closest I can find is the [yield operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) but I cannot find any built-in method that convert an array to such collection/generator.

Assuming I have a large array/collection, is there any built-in functions that defer the executions until they are actually needed?

Sometimes an operation can be like this (just an example) and defered execution may be more favorable:

```
var foo = bar.filter(pred1).map(q => calc(q.value)).filter(q => Boolean(q)).map(finalMap);
```

Here's an example (but 4 arrays are allocated in the process):

```js
const adjustedMultiplier = [1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.7];

const data = [
  {
    name: "Person 1",
    fromId: 1,
    score: 9,
    details: {} // More data
  },
  {
    name: "Person 2",
    fromId: 1,
    score: 6,
    details: {} // More data
  },
  {
    name: "Person 3",
    fromId: 3,
    score: 8,
    details: {} // More data
  },
  // More
];

const expectedResult = data
  .filter(q => q.fromId < 3)
  .map(q => ({
    name: q.name,
    adjustedScore: q.score * adjustedMultiplier[q.fromId]
  }))
  .filter(q => q.adjustedScore >= 8);
console.log(expectedResult);
```

Comment: I understand you are looking for a way to execute some action in the future, can you provide a more concise example, a dataset and the expected result ?

Comment: @brk in the above example, the final collection/array should be `[2]`. I don't think an actual dataset is needed here but sure I will edit and give an example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for a higher order function. In that case you can also explore closure. In the below code a function is created which return another function. You can call the inner function whith the data and execute it whenever required

```js
const adjustedMultiplier = [1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.7];

const data = [{
    name: "Person 1",
    fromId: 1,
    score: 9,
    details: {} // More data
  },
  {
    name: "Person 2",
    fromId: 1,
    score: 6,
    details: {} // More data
  },
  {
    name: "Person 3",
    fromId: 3,
    score: 8,
    details: {} // More data
  }
];


function deferFn() {
  return function(val) {
    return data
      .filter(q => q.fromId < 3)
      .map(q => ({
        name: q.name,
        adjustedScore: q.score * adjustedMultiplier[q.fromId]
      }))
      .filter(q => q.adjustedScore >= 8);
  }

}
const expectedResult = deferFn()
console.log(expectedResult); // this will not execute the function
console.log(expectedResult(data)) // this will execute the function
```

Comment: This correctly defer the whole function but the issue I am having is the smaller functions like `filter` and `map`. In your case, when executing the function returned by `deferFn`, the 4 methods are executed one by one, each would make a new array.

Comment: For example, in C#, calling `arr.Where(q => q < 2)` would result in an `IEnumerable<int>` (**not** `int[]`), which is something similar to Javascript's [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). Therefore, further function calls also work with that generator instead of actually allocate and populate a whole new array.

Answer (score -1):

```js
try this

var result = a.filter(x=>x<2).map(x=>x+1)

Refer this [link][1]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).